# QMediaPlayer. Не воспроизводит аудио

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

При компиляции такого вот кода:

```
QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer;
player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(":/music.mp3"));
player->play();
```

Программа выдает:

> defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for -
>   "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"

И аудио не работает. Как решить даную проблему?

ОС Ubuntu 16.04; Qt 5.7.0. Qt Creator 4.1.0

Comment: Глупый вопрос конечно, а у вас колонки есть на кпомьютере? Или может не установлены драйвера на устройство?

Comment: @Unick, колонки есть и драйвера имеються.

Comment: @Unick, на сколько я понимаю проблема эта связана с какой то dll-библиотекой.

Comment: https://forum.qt.io/topic/40615/solved-qmediaplayer-reporting-no-service-available-in-latest-qt-update/2 чем-то похожая проблема на вашу

Answer (score 3):

Как оказалось даная проблема присутствует на ОС Ubuntu 14 и выше. На Windows, насколько я проверял, этой проблемы не должно быть (во всяком случае у меня нет).
Решил я это дело переустановкой GStreamer'a версии 0.10 (apt-get install gstreamer0.10).

Так же, (в моем случае), данный код: `QUrl::fromLocalFile(":/music.mp3")` не локализирует папку з проектом и не находит нужный файл. Поэтому нужно указывать полный путь к файлу: `QUrl::fromLocalFile(QApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/music.wav")`.
Еще важный момент - мой GStreamer не захотел работать с форматом .mp3, поэтому декодировал его в .wav.
После всех этих процедур, аудио начало воспроизводиться.